# Is it true that $\lambda^2=k$ here?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $A\in\mathcal{M}_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ and $A^\dagger A=k\operatorname{Id}$ where $k\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, also we assume that $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with multiplicity $3$ (denote the eigenvectors by $a_1,a_2,a_3$. Consider the following operator: $M=k(A^t-A)$ I showed that $Ma_1=k(\frac{k}{\lambda}a_1-\lambda a_1)$, now I suspect that $\lambda^2=k$ but I can't show it from $A^\dagger A=k\operatorname{Id}$ alone, can anyone shine light here with some hint?

Answer (score 0):

$Aa_1=\lambda a_1$ implies $a_1^\top A^\top A a_1 = (Aa_1)^\top (Aa_1) = (\lambda a_1)^\top (\lambda a_1) = \lambda^2 a_1^\top a_1$. Since you know $A^\top A = kI$, you also have $a_1^\top A^\top A a_1 = ka_1^\top a_1$. So $k=\lambda^2$.